# Filesystem keeps getting corrupted

Tags: filesystem, ubuntu-mate, read-only

**Foreword: filesystems setting**: Ubuntu uses two partitions:

- `/` is on my SSD (partition `/dev/sda5`)
- `/home/` is on my HDD (partition `/dev/sdb2`)

**Problem (chronologically)**:

1. **Read-only `/home/`**: using my Ubuntu as usual, I ran into the problem that my  `/home/` (on my HDD) became Read-only.
2. **Rescue mode**: upon rebooting, Ubuntu directly went into rescue mode.
3. **fsck**: From a live USB, I repaired the  HDDpartition where the home is using `fsck.ext4`. There was nothing to repair on the SSD partition.
4. **GUI, then Read-only**: Ubuntu started again on GUI, but after a few minutes, the `/home/` went "Read-only" again.
5. **Loop over 2-4**: I have been repeating steps 2-4 a few times. Every time `fsck` fixes the partition on which my `/home/` is, and I can run Ubuntu with GUI, but after a random amount of time, the same problem occurs.  This happens even if I do nothing but try to `touch` a file every few minutes.

**Possible causes**:

- **Hard reboot** (that I did 3 hours before the problem started happening)
- **Packages update** (that I performed some tens of minutes before the problem started happening)

The package update was:

```
Start-Date: 2021-04-21  16:18:16
Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade
Requested-By: xavier (1000)
Upgrade: libseccomp2:amd64 (2.4.3-1ubuntu3.18.04.3, 2.5.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), ruby2.5:amd64 (2.5.1-1ubuntu1.8, 2.5.1-1ubuntu1.9), libsystemd0:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.45, 237-3ubuntu10.46), libsystemd0:i386 (237-3ubuntu10.45, 237-3ubuntu10.46), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (89.0.4389.128-1, 90.0.4430.85-1), skypeforlinux:amd64 (8.69.0.77, 8.71.0.36), udev:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.45, 237-3ubuntu10.46), libudev1:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.45, 237-3ubuntu10.46), libudev1:i386 (237-3ubuntu10.45, 237-3ubuntu10.46), libruby2.5:amd64 (2.5.1-1ubuntu1.8, 2.5.1-1ubuntu1.9), libcaca0:amd64 (0.99.beta19-2ubuntu0.18.04.1, 0.99.beta19-2ubuntu0.18.04.2), chromium-browser:amd64 (89.0.4389.90-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 90.0.4430.72-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), systemd-sysv:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.45, 237-3ubuntu10.46), chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 (89.0.4389.90-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 90.0.4430.72-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), zotero:amd64 (5.0.96, 5.0.96.2-1), libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.45, 237-3ubuntu10.46), systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.45, 237-3ubuntu10.46), libnss-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.45, 237-3ubuntu10.46), chromium-browser-l10n:amd64 (89.0.4389.90-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 90.0.4430.72-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-04-21  16:19:14
```

There is no update of the linux-headers among these. I did a kernel update ([log here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/zV9g7Gdp9V/)), but that was 3 days ago, and after that I have been using my laptop intensively without running into an issue.

**Less likely causes**:

- **Hardware issue**(?): there an NTFS partition on the same HDD whose Linux partition keeps getting corrupted. I use this NTFS partition on Windows to store some heavy files. However, I ran a check on this partition using Windows' toolset, and it does not detect any issue. This may not rule out hardware issues entirely, but I don't feel like my HDD is falling into pieces.

**My guess**: I do feel that there is an issue with one of the packages I have updated. However, I cannot say what most of them are used for, so I don't have any suspect I could start with. Also, I could be wrong regarding the update, but I don't know how to diagnose further the issue. If someone has a clue regarding the problem or how to further check what is going on, it would be very helpful.

**Additional logs**:

- [journalctl](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/b5pBFYxrs7/) when ubuntu starts in rescue mode.
- [dmesg](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/8XvmpRzCFC/) when ubuntu starts in rescue mode.
- [fsck.ext4](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/RQ2bpjr6nb/) outputs this when repairing `/dev/sdb2` (where /home/ is) from a live USB ubuntu.

**General setting**:

- Computer: ASUS ROG laptop
- Linux: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, Mate flavor 1.20.1, kernel 4.15.0-142-generic x86-64

### Update (2021-04-23)

As per @guiverc's comment, I have run a long disk self-test using `smartctl` from a live usb drive. Below are the full smartctl logs.

From what I can gather (based mostly on the package creator's [explanations](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6983)), the overall conclusion is that I should be concerned over my HDD.

On the positive side, `SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED` is encouraging, as is the fact that the SMART attributes' values are all well above thresholds.

On a much less positive side, there has been 60 errors during (what I think is) the time `smartctl` ran, or a little before that. Such a high number seem to be a cause for concern. Also, the self-test log shows status `Completed: read failure`, which also feels worrying.

Note that I haven't run an `fsck` fix before running `smartctl`, but don't know whether it matters.

Given what I understand, I feel the reading of this log calls for being cautious, backing up my HDD (already was, mostly) and replacing it with a new one.

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-42-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABD...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100
Serial Number:    17POPDQKT
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 782d0abaf
Firmware Version: AX0R5J
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Apr 22 11:53:17 2021 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 112) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 236) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1660
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3639
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   084   084   000    Old_age   Always       -       6487
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   172   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2859
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       630
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       85
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       27933
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 13/51)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   088   088   000    Old_age   Always       -       5055
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       273
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 60 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 60 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6480 hours (270 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 10 78 dd dd 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00dddd78 = 14540152

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 10 78 dd dd 40 00      00:29:14.662  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:29:14.661  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:29:14.661  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:29:14.660  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:29:14.660  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 59 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6480 hours (270 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 d0 78 dd dd 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00dddd78 = 14540152

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 d0 78 dd dd 40 00      00:29:10.778  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 c8 70 dd dd 40 00      00:29:10.777  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 c0 68 dd dd 40 00      00:29:10.765  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 b8 60 dd dd 40 00      00:29:10.764  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 b0 58 dd dd 40 00      00:29:10.764  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 58 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6480 hours (270 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 40 78 dd dd 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00dddd78 = 14540152

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 b8 48 00 e6 dd 40 00      00:29:10.543  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 40 00 dc dd 40 00      00:29:06.765  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 38 00 d2 dd 40 00      00:29:06.754  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 00 c8 dd 40 00      00:29:06.728  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 e8 28 a0 49 29 40 00      00:29:06.716  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 57 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6480 hours (270 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 b8 78 dd dd 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00dddd78 = 14540152

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 b8 78 dd dd 40 00      00:25:20.185  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 b0 a8 6b ad 40 00      00:25:20.184  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:25:20.184  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:25:20.184  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:25:20.184  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 56 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6480 hours (270 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 80 78 dd dd 40  Error: WP at LBA = 0x00dddd78 = 14540152

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 10 90 00 c8 27 40 00      00:25:19.960  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 88 a8 6a ad 40 00      00:25:19.960  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 80 78 dd dd 40 00      00:25:16.323  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 d8 78 38 bc 16 40 00      00:25:16.322  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 70 38 b2 16 40 00      00:25:16.310  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       00%      6485         450747768

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

As per @paladin's request, here is my `/dev/fstab`.

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                                                                     fstab.txt                                                                                               
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=09c3311b-f37d-48ca-b0bf-1001574bf539 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=6896-40E1  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=40d7f02e-01ff-4c43-80d9-4fcd8b0139a5   /home    ext4          nodev,nosuid       0       2
```

Comment: The most common cause is a failing hard drive.

Comment: Have you checked the health of your hardware (staring with drives, ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools but GUI tools can be used too), though PSU, capacitor issues etc. can also cause errors so I'd suggest checking your hardware...   I'd suggest doing checks using a *live* system too, and don't forget Ubuntu Mate 18.04.5 is in it's last days of supported life - https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-18-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/23966/1

Comment: Are you sure you mean `write-only` and not `read-only`? May you please post `cat /etc/fstab`?

Comment: @guiverc and David: Thanks, I have added an update section in my post with the output of smartctl. From what I could piece together, my HDD indeed isn't going so well.

Comment: @paladin you are right of course, not sure how I came up with this one (fixed.) I have added the fstab at the end of my post.

Comment: Good that you've already used smartctl. Now listen, when SMART already has reported a problem with your disk, stop using that defect disk immediately or you may face data loses. Get another disk and immediately backup your old disk and never use your old disk again.